# I am trying To play video using Firebase but it show me DefaultHttpDataSourceFactory is Deprecated

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, exoplayer

[I provided image link please see image i got so many errors[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/78m7S.png) private void initializeExoplayerView(String videoUrl) {

try{
BandwidthMeter bandwidthMeter = new DefaultBandwidthMeter.Builder(this).build();
TrackSelector trackSelector = new DefaultTrackSelector(this,newAdaptiveTrackSelection.Factory(bandwidthMeter));
exoPlayer = (SimpleExoPlayer) ExoPlayerFactory.newSimpleInstance(this, trackSelector);
Uri videouri = Uri.parse(videoUrl);

```
        DefaultHttpDataSourceFactory dataSourceFactory = new DefaultHttpDataSourceFactory("exoplayer_video");
        ExtractorsFactory extractorsFactory = new DefaultExtractorsFactory();
        MediaSource mediaSource = new ExtractorMediaSource(videouri, dataSourceFactory, extractorsFactory, null, null);
        exoPlayerView.setPlayer(exoPlayer);
        exoPlayer.prepare(mediaSource);
        exoPlayer.setPlayWhenReady(true);

    } catch (Exception e){
        Log.e("TAG", "Error : " + e.toString());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use the new Factory for HTTP Data source instead 'DefaultHttpDataSource.Factory'.

https://exoplayer.dev/doc/reference/com/google/android/exoplayer2/upstream/DefaultHttpDataSource.Factory.html

You can find examples of it's use in the ExoPlayer GitHub repository in the test and demo code - for example, if you look at the extract below and follow the calls its makes:

```js
public void start_playlistCanBlockReloadLowLatencyFullSegment_correctMsnAndPartParams()
      throws IOException, TimeoutException, InterruptedException {
    List<HttpUrl> httpUrls =
        enqueueWebServerResponses(
            new String[] {
              "/master.m3u8",
              "/media0/playlist.m3u8",
              "/media0/playlist.m3u8?_HLS_msn=14&_HLS_part=0"
            },
            getMockResponse(SAMPLE_M3U8_LIVE_MASTER),
            getMockResponse(SAMPLE_M3U8_LIVE_MEDIA_CAN_BLOCK_RELOAD_LOW_LATENCY_FULL_SEGMENT),
            getMockResponse(SAMPLE_M3U8_LIVE_MEDIA_CAN_BLOCK_RELOAD_LOW_LATENCY_FULL_SEGMENT_NEXT));

    List<HlsMediaPlaylist> mediaPlaylists =
        runPlaylistTrackerAndCollectMediaPlaylists(
            new DefaultHttpDataSource.Factory(),
            Uri.parse(mockWebServer.url("/master.m3u8").toString()),
            /* awaitedMediaPlaylistCount= */ 2);
```

from: https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer/blob/0ba317b1337eaa789f05dd6c5241246478a3d1e5/library/hls/src/test/java/com/google/android/exoplayer2/source/hls/playlist/DefaultHlsPlaylistTrackerTest.java

Comment: i got this error,Cannot resolve constructor 'Factory(com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.BandwidthMeter)' I got this error, 'Factory' is abstract; cannot be instantiated

Comment: It is hard to comment without your updated code but the easiest thing is probably for you to look at some working examples of its use - answer is updated with an example from the ExoPlayer repository itself.